# Incremented index on polygons using virtual layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer

I would like to use a virtual layer that numbering a layer of polygons.
This numbering should be incremented along another layers of polylines.
Example:

- polyline 1 :start_point = Index : 0 ; end_point index = 8
- polyline 2 : start_point = Index : 9 ; end_point index = 16
- polyline 3 : etc.

[image]

At the moment, I use a [virtual layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436427/incremented-index-on-a-split-polyline-in-qgis/436443#436443) that create polylines with the numbering expected :

```
select geometry, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id, lpcent) as ID FROM 
(
select st_intersection(l.geometry, p.geometry) as geometry,
       l.id,
       ST_Line_Locate_Point(l.geometry, st_startpoint(st_intersection(l.geometry, p.geometry))) as lpcent
from myPolygon p
 join myLine l
 on st_intersects(l.geometry, p.geometry)
)
```

The next step on my workflow was to match the attribute of the new polyline numbering, by location, to the polygons layer.

I now need to skip this step, and get directly polygons with the numbering as result.

Can I do this into the same virtual layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you don't want the computed ID to be on the line but rather on the polygon.

You can adapt the query to select the polygon attributes (`p.*`) and to return all of them (`*`). If you don't want to include the `line %` and `line id`, you can replace `*` by a list of polygon attributes, including `geometry` (ex: `select geometry, poly_id, poly_attribute2 ...`)

```sql
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by line_ID, line_pcent) as new_ID 
FROM 
(
select p.*,
       l.id line_ID,
       ST_Line_Locate_Point(l.geometry, st_startpoint(st_intersection(l.geometry, p.geometry))) as line_pcent
from myPolygon p
 join myLine l
 on st_intersects(l.geometry, p.geometry)
)
```

Comment: hello, it works but I have to complete ID column of myLine. I use to fill this colum using row_number function, but it adds a previous step. Is there a way to add this function into the virtual layer?

Comment: Do you mean you don't have a line id and want to generate one? sure, but the result could be ordered in an unexpected manner...  to follow your screen shot and order from right to left, replace `l.id line_ID,` with `st_maxX(l.geometry) line_ID,` and `order by line_ID, line_pcent` with `order by line_ID desc, line_pcent asc`

Comment: I mean, myLine doesn't have id field. I tried with the change you suggested me, but it seems it doesn't work : the 1rst line has the max number, the second line has the 1rst number, and the third line has the third number.